# How to reset an Android tablet?

Tags: tablet

I got an Android tablet that my dad bought short before he passed away.. I'm trying to reset it to factory settings, because we do not know the PIN for it. By using `volume up + power button` it boots to a menu in Chinese. Using Google lens to translate I chose `clear eMMC` and after it restarted it looked like it worked, but after choosing the language settings and so on it got to the screen which say "This phone was reset to factory settings. To access it please use previous PIN." I tried to use Google account instead, but this got me back to the PIN as of course it's not the same account as my dad registered with. So I'm running circles here.

Could anyone help? It's a Lenovo TB-X606X

Comment: It sounds for security reasons you will be unable to reset the device without the pin.

Comment: Mediatek MT6762 SoC try bootloader unlock with [mtkclient](https://github.com/bkerler/mtkclient) (or figure out FRP partition and erase it)